# elasticsearch query traceID

Tags: elasticsearch

I put some data into elasticsearch through logstash.
Then I run the first command:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=traceID=1428074818422&pretty=true'
```

the elasticsearch return the result that which traceID is 1428074818422.

But when I use the second command:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_search？pretty=true' -d'{
    "query":{
    "term" : {"traceID" : "1428074818422"}
    }
}'
```

the elastcsearch can not find any result.

I want to kown the reason about this problem and how can I solve it,thanks.

Comment: is your traceId `string` or `number`? try to pass number instead of string.

Comment: your first query should be written as follows `curl 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=traceID:1428074818422&pretty=true'` - note the colon after `traceID`. So possibly the first query isn't returning the right data anyway?

Comment: yeah , u are right, but how about the second query?

Answer (score 0):

1. the `？` should be `?`
2. you should specify the header 'Content-Type'

try this:

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "query":{
    "term" : {"traceID" : "1428074818422"}
    }
}'
```